# Within a stone's throw of somewhere

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I was reading a book - "Steps to Understanding" by L.A. Hill - when i saw the sentence below:

> One day he saw an advertisement for a suitable house in Hampshire which was claimed to be **within a stone's throw** of  a railway station.

I know what "throw" means. I was expecting to see a kind of distance determiner after the word "within".
But what does exactly mean to be "within a stone's throw of somewhere"? How much is this distance? What does it mean? Does it mean that If someone throws a stone from the train station, The house is in the range of the distance which the stone travels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not meant to be taken literally. It simply means *close (by)*. There is no fixed distance that constitutes a "stone's throw", much like how "close" or "near" are not fixed.

> [**within a stone's throw (of something)**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/within+a+stone%27s+throw) and (just) a stone's throw away (from something); (just) a stone's throw (from something)
>   Fig. very close (to something). (Possibly as close as the distance one could throw a stone. It usually refers to a distance much greater than one could throw a stone.) *The police department was located within a stone's throw of our house. We live in Carbondale, and that's just a stone's throw away from the Mississippi River. Come visit. We live just a stone's throw away.*
>   (TFD)

Comment: Also note that the phrase is corny. [Example](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/The_Blunder_Years/Quotes): **Homer:** "Yup, the old quarry is just a stone's throw away." **Lisa:** "Stop saying that, Dad." **Homer:** "Never!"

Comment: Hahaha. I wouldn't say it's corny though. Homer's usage was corny (seemed like a dad joke), but I didn't think "corny" when I read the OP.

Comment: Hmm. It's at least somehow cutesy, rustic, colourful. I think the advertiser is trying to increase the charm of the house with that phrase.

Comment: Yes! I couldn't think of the right word. All I can think of is "quaint" at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

"stone's throw" refers to a short distance away. Obviously most of us can't throw a stone too far, so people use this phrase to describe two places that are not far apart.

> **a stone’s throw (away)**
>   ​ 
>   a short distance:
>
> *The animal was sitting just a stone's throw away from us*.
>
> *The lodge is within a stone’s throw of the ski slopes*.
>
> Source: [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/a-stone-s-throw-away)